# Functional style dependency injection to make business logic unit-testable

Tags: functional-programming, node.js, typescript

My project is a blogging app, which is a recruitment assignment. It is now finished and working.

Following function handles updating a comment votes, very similar as on StackExchange sites, preventing duplicated votes and ensuring single vote per IP address.

I am not sure how to make the following function unit testable in a functional way. The dependency here is the database provider, which is a TypeORM instance.
It involves several database calls and a transaction, which make it difficult for me to make it testable.

I know how to use currying to "inject" simple dependencies such as configuration, but database manager is a complicated object which would be very difficult to mock.

To explain more, there are two tables in the database, `Comment` which holds the vote count (`votes`) and `CommentVote` which holds individual votes for IP address.

Full code [here](https://github.com/jiri-matejka/applifting-cat-blog/blob/master/backend/src/domain/comments.ts#L43).

```js
export async function changeCommentVote(
  commentId: string,
  ipAddress: string,
  voteDelta: 1 | -1,
) {
  const result = await dbDataSource.transaction(async (manager) => {
    async function handleExistingVotes(): Promise<Result<statusCodeType>> {
      // check if this IP already voted
      const existingVote = await manager.findOneBy(CommentVote, {
        commentId,
        ipAddress,
      });
      if (existingVote && existingVote.vote === voteDelta) {
        // repeated vote in the same direction is prohibited
        return error({
          code: STATUS_CODES.BAD_REQUEST,
          message: 'Already voted',
        });
      } else if (existingVote) {
        // voting with the opossite for the second time (e.g. first up, second down)
        // it means that user is withdrawing his vote
        await manager.delete(CommentVote, existingVote);
        // here the status code are not expressive enough,
        // a custom codes should be included in the body, but let's keep it for now
        return ok(STATUS_CODES.OK);
      } else {
        // first vote
        await manager.insert(CommentVote, {
          commentId,
          ipAddress,
          vote: voteDelta,
        });
        return ok(STATUS_CODES.CREATED);
      }
    }

    const resultFromExistingVotes = await handleExistingVotes();

    if (isError(resultFromExistingVotes)) {
      return resultFromExistingVotes;
    }

    const updateResult = await manager
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .from(Comment, 'comment')
      .setParameter('delta', voteDelta)
      .update({ votes: () => 'votes + :delta' })
      .where('id = :id', { id: commentId })
      .returning(['id', 'votes'])
      .execute();

    return updateResult.affected === 1
      ? ok({
          code: resultFromExistingVotes.value,
          newVotes: updateResult.raw[0].votes as number,
        })
      : error({ code: STATUS_CODES.NOT_FOUND });
  });

  if (isOk(result)) {
    // uses websockets to send a realtime response to the browser
    commentCallbacks.afterVotingCallback({
      commentId,
      votes: result.value!.newVotes,
    });
  }

  return result;
}
```